# git is not installed Failed to start Git process: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/git-core" (in directory "."): error=13, Permission denied

Tags: linux, flutter, android-studio

I'm getting this error every time I open a flutter project I downloaded from Github.
Git is not installed Failed to start Git process: Cannot run program "/usr/lib/git-core" (in directory "."): error=13, Permission denied.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you please explain more how you download the project? also Do you have `git` installed on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

I actually fixed the problem. I just had to run `which git` on my terminal after installing git. Then on the android studio navigate to; File>Settings>Version Control>Git, on the path to Git executable add the directory displayed on your terminal then click test and apply.

Comment: This should not fix the issue. This just checks if the path to a git installation is existing in the environment.